# findBy appear to update the database

Tags: performance, grails, findby

I have the following code:

```
println "@@@@@@@@ RUNNING ProfessionaCustomer - ${pcCounter} under ${accountCustomer.customerNumber}  Professional SQLid ${it.id}"
def professionalCustomerId = it.customerId
def professionalCustomer = ProfessionalCustomer.findByCustomerNumber(professionalCustomerId)
```

I have SQL logging on and I get:

```
@@@@@@@@ RUNNING ProfessionaCustomer - 31 under 106450  Professional SQLid 100759
Hibernate: update base_domain set version=?, account_name=?, address_line1=?,  address_line2=?, city=?, customer_number=?, date_created=?, disabled=?, last_updated=?, postal_code=?, primary_phone=?, state_or_province=? where id=? and version=?
Hibernate: update base_domain set version=?, address1=?, address2=?, city=?, customer_number=?, date_created=?, disabled=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, last_updated=?, middle_name=?, phone_number=?, postal_code=?, state=? where id=? and version=?
Hibernate: insert into account_customer_professionals (account_customer_id, professional_customer_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_3_0_, this_.version as version2_3_0_, this_.address1 as address70_3_0_, this_.address2 as address71_3_0_, this_.city as city7_3_0_, this_.customer_number as customer8_3_0_, this_.date_created as date_cre9_3_0_, this_.disabled as disable10_3_0_, this_.first_name as first_n19_3_0_, this_.last_name as last_na20_3_0_, this_.last_updated as last_up11_3_0_, this_.middle_name as middle_72_3_0_, this_.phone_number as phone_n73_3_0_, this_.postal_code as postal_12_3_0_, this_.state as state74_3_0_ from base_domain this_ where this_.class='com.eveo.nplate.model.ProfessionalCustomer' and this_.customer_number=? limit ?
```

Which is updating the DB. This would explain why this is so slow, but I can't see any reason for this to happen.

Why would 'findBy' cause an update?

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate doesn't immediately execute creates, updates, or deletes until it thinks it has to - it waits as long as possible (although it's rather pessimistic) and only flushes these changes when you tell it to, or when it thinks it needs to. In general the only time it will flush without an explicit call is when running queries. This is because any of the new instances, updated instances, and deleted instances that are in-memory (cached in the Hibernate Session, the 1<sup>st</sup>-level cache) could affect the query results, so they must be flushed to the database so you get the proper results for your query.

One exception to this is calling `save()` on a new instance. Grails flushes this because typically the id is assigned by the database, either via an auto-increment column or a sequence. To ensure that the in-memory state is the same as the database, it flushes the `save()` call so it can retrieve the id and set it in the instance. But if you retrieve a persistence instance (e.g. with a `get()` call, or with a criteria query, finder, etc.) and modify it, calling `save()` on that does not get automatically flushed. The same goes for `delete()` calls - not flushed.

Think of `delete()` and `save()` calls on persistent instances as messages to Hibernate that the action should be performed "eventually".

So when you execute a finder, or a criteria, "where", or HQL query, Hibernate will flush any un-flushed changes for you. If you don't want that to happen (e.g. in a custom domain class validator closure) you can run the query in a separate session, e.g. with the [withNewSession](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html) method.

If you don't flush the session at all, either explicitly on the `Session` instance or by adding `flush:true` to a `save` or `delete` call, the session will be flushed, since Grails registers an OpenSessionInView interceptor that starts a session at the beginning of each request, and flushes and closes it at the end. This helps with lazy loading; since there's a session open and bound to a `ThreadLocal` in a known location, Hibernate and GORM (via Spring's `HibernateTemplate`) can use that open session to retrieve lazy-loaded collections and instances on-demand after the query runs.

Note also that you do not need to flush in a transaction. The transaction manager is a Spring `HibernateTransactionManager` that flushes before committing.

Answer (score 2):

Probably there was some transaction in the session that was not persisted in the database.

When you ran the `findBy` hibernate took advantage of the connection to run the two queries. I believe this is what happened.

Comment: Victor, thanks so much for your input. Of course - it's clear now.